# Evaluate $y'''+3y''+3y'+y = e^{it}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

$y'''+3y''+3y'+y = e^{it}$

I've got this method of undermined coefficients but i am unable to find the particular solution. I got the complimentary solution as $$Y_c = {C_1}{e^{it}}+ {C_2}{t}{e^{it}}+{C_3}{t^{2}}{e^{it}}$$ but keep getting the wrong answer when I try to find the particular.

Comment: $i$ is not a root of the characteristic equation, but $-1$ is a root.

Comment: Changing the question, especially after someone has answered, is phenomenally rude.

Answer (score 1):

For $y'''+3y''+3y'+y = 0$ characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^3+3\lambda^2 + 3\lambda+1 = (\lambda+1)^3$, so complementary solution is $y_c = {C_1}{e^{-t}}+ {C_2}{t}{e^{-t}}+{C_3}{t^{2}}{e^{-t}}$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut It matters in both, though, because if it were actually involving $e^{it}$ then the particular solution here would have to look different.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut it matters as well, because finding particular solution in case when root of polynomial is in exponent in right side is a bit different.

Answer (score 1):

$$y'''+3y''+3y'+y = e^{it}$$
Try for the particular solution:
$$y_p=Ae^{it}$$
$$ -iA-3A+3iA+A=1$$
$$A=\dfrac 1{2(i-1)}$$
$$A=\dfrac {i+1}{2(i-1)(i+1)}$$
$$A=\dfrac {i+1}{2(i^2-1)}$$
$$A=-\dfrac 14 (i+1)$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

\begin{align*}
y''' + 3y'' + 3y' + y = e^{it} & \Longleftrightarrow (y'''+ y'') + 2(y'' + y') + (y' + y) = e^{it}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (y' + y)'' + 2(y' + y)' + (y' + y) = e^{it}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow u'' + 2u' + u = e^{it}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (u' + u)' + (u' + u) = e^{it}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow v' + v = e^{it}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (ve^{t})' = e^{t + it}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (ue^{t})'' = e^{t + it}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (ye^{t})''' = e^{t + it}
\end{align*}